# Is it true that difference of independent events independent?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

It is well know that a Brownian motion $(W(t))_t$ has independent increments.
More precisely, given any $0\leq t<s,$ the increment $W(t)-W(s)$ is independent of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr F(t)$ generated up till time $t$.

Then I believe that given any $0\leq t<u_1<u_2,$ the increment $W(u_2) -W(u_1)$ is also independent of $\mathscr F(t).$

Reason is as follows:

Since $W(u_2) - W(u_1) =(W(u_2 )-W(t))-((W(u_1 )-W(t))) $ and both $(W(u_2 )-W(t))$ and $((W(u_1 )-W(t)))$ are independent of $F(t)$.
**As difference between independent events is still independent**, so $W(u_2) - W(u_1)$ is independent from $\mathscr{F}(t).$

I am not very sure the validity of the bold statement above.

Comment: $W(u_2)-W(u_1)$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_{u_1}$ and $\mathscr{F}_t \subset \mathscr{F}_{u_1},$ so $W(u_2)-W(u_1)$ must be independent of $\mathscr{F}_t.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X,Y)$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\varphi(X,Y)$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ for any measurable function $\varphi$.

---

In your case, use the fact that $W_{u_2}-W_{u_1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{u_1}$ and $\mathcal{F}_t\subset \mathcal{F}_{u_1}$.

Comment: Do you have a proof or reference for the statement above?

Comment: @Idonknow Just use the definition of independence.